# Creating an instance of a structure with unexported sub-structures in Go

Tags: go, slack-api, slack

I am trying to manually create an instance of the type ReactionAddedEvent given [here, in nlopes' Go Slack library](https://github.com/nlopes/slack/blob/master/websocket_reactions.go#L22). However, the sub-type reactionItem is unexported, which leads me to receive the error `./bot_test.go:111: cannot refer to unexported name slack.reactionItem` when trying to instantiate the object.

Here is my code:

`m := &slack.ReactionAddedEvent{
        Item: &slack.reactionItem{
            File: &slack.File{
                Preview: "Test",
                URLPrivate: "http://google.com",
            },
        },
        Reaction: "white_check_mark",
    }`

When I remove the identifier `&slack.reactionItem` from line 2 in that snippet, I get instead the error: `./bot_test.go:112: missing type in composite literal`, obviously.

Is there any way for me to instantiate an object of this type with the parameters I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if `slack` here refers to the `nlopes` library, the `slack.ReactionAddedEvent` structure's `Item` field is not a pointer, so you can't store an address of a `slack.reactionItem` struct into that field anyway.  Second, the `File` field of `slack.reactionItem` is a string, not a structure.

Third, even if the above isn't/weren't the case, if the types are not exported, but the fields themselves are, you can't assemble the structure in a single literal.  Instead, you'll have to manually set those fields after creating the structure variable:

```
m := &slack.ReactionAddedEvent{Reaction: "white_check_mark"}
m.Item.File.Preview = "Test"
m.Item.File.URLPrivate = "http://google.com"
```

But again, if you're using the `nlopes` library, that won't work because the `File` field isn't actually a structure:
https://github.com/nlopes/slack/blob/master/websocket_reactions.go

And fourth, if the type isn't exported, that's probably a good sign that you *shouldn't* be manipulating objects of that type.  In this case, in the `nlopes` library, those structures are only intended to be used for unmarshalling and then handling events from JSON messages.

Comment: Why would that package export ReactionAddedEvent at first place ?

Comment: It's a typedef of an unexported structure, but it looks like it's an exported type (with exported fields) so clients of the library can implement handlers for the event types.  From their example fields: https://github.com/nlopes/slack/blob/master/examples/websocket/websocket.go

Comment: The idea, though, seems to be that the events are _created_ by the slack library from events that are received as JSON messages, and then converted into these exported-type Events that the client can setup a handler for.  The client isn't supposed to create the events themselves.